# REST API is not working on android device

Tags: php, android, rest

I have build REST api in php for android device. I have tested the api in many tools which are available on the internet such as hackst.com and via plugins in google and mozilla and gettign proper response, but when the actually making api calls from the android mobile it is not working properly. it is throwing to my hosting servers error page. I am a beginner can anybody help me...

Comment: POst some android code here

Comment: Are you using json to request data?

Comment: Yes... Now it's working fine thaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you may not have add the INternet permission in manifest like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```